# Vuejs on select change components property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an ace Editor component which basically Shows me an ace Editor in my view.
The component Looks like this:

```
<template>
    <editor v-model="content" @init="editorInit" lang="javascript" theme="chaos" width="100%" height="100%"></editor>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [],

        data () {
            return {
                language: 'javascript',
                content: "",
            }
        },

        components: {
            editor: require('vue2-ace-editor'),
        },

        methods: {
            editorInit () {
                require('brace/ext/language_tools'); //language extension prerequsite...
                require('brace/mode/html');
                require('brace/mode/javascript');    //language
                require('brace/mode/less');
                require('brace/theme/ambiance');
                require('brace/theme/chaos');
                require('brace/theme/chrome');
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Now I created an additional component to select another theme and Change the theme style in my Editor.
It Looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-select
            :items="themes"
            v-model="themeSelection"
            label="Select"
            single-line
        ></v-select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    data () {
        return {
            themeSelection: null,
            themes: [
                { text: 'ambiance' },
                { text: 'chaos' },
                { text: 'chrome' },
            ]
        }
    }    
}
</script>
```

Now I would like to Change the lang property in my aceeditorcomponent after I select a different theme how can I do this?

```
<editor v-model="content" @init="editorInit" lang="JavaScript" theme="chaosNEEDSTOBECHANGEDONSELECT" width="100%" height="100%"></editor>
```

Comment: [.sync Modifier](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)